# How to get uploaded file name after rename in Fat-Free Framework?

Tags: fat-free-framework

I use this to save uploaded file

```
$web = \Web::instance();

$uploadPath=$f3->get('uploadFolder');
$f3->set('UPLOADS',$uploadPath);

$overwrite = true;
$slug = true;

$files = $web->receive(function($file,$formFieldName){

        if(file_exists($file['name'])){
            //$file['name'] = $f3->get('uploadFolder').'rename.jpg'; // this is error, how to get path from config.ini here?
            $file['name'] = 'assets/img/upload/rename.jpg';
            move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $file['name']);
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    },
    $overwrite,
    $slug
);

$savedFile=array_keys($files)[0];
```

This only get the file path before rename, how can I get the path after rename?

And how to get config in callback function?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get any uploads directory from config or call `move_uploaded_file` manually yourself.. that's all part of the `$web->receive` method.

The `$files` array will contain the full final path (incl. the renamed file name).

When you return `true` in the callback function, the uploaded file is moved to the upload folder defined in the `UPLOADS` F3 variable. Just check for file sizes, mime-types etc. in the callback function if you need. That's all you usually need to do.

Comment: If I return true, it will overwrite the existing file. If I set $overwrite = false, it will not call the callback function

Comment: Ok sry, I didn’t noticed at first that you’re trying to avoid file name collisions. Usually I use the UPLOADS dir only as a temp storage. I use the files returned from web->receive to move the files to their final folders. You could check if any file is already existing there and alter the file name during move, but not within the callback, that’s right... perhaps it would be possible to pass $file as reference, than it would be possible to change the name within the callback. Need to test that.